# how to change font size and colour of a list in itext?

Tags: java, itext

I'm using itextpdf for generating my pdf file. I have a list which should be added in a cell of a table. The problem is I can't change the font size of the list present in the cell of the table?
Here my code is

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
List fruitList = new List(List.UNORDERED);
//fruitList.setListSymbol(new Chunk("", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 6)));
fruitList.add("Mango");
fruitList.add("Apple");
fruitList.add("Orange");
cell.addElement(fruitList);
table.addCell(cell);
```

Here I have added setListSymbol for the created list. But the font or its size is not getting changed. But font is getting changed for cell's which doesn't have list in it. How to change the size and font of the list?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You set the list symbol to `""`, which means you don't want a list symbol. If you don't want a list symbol, why are you creating a list? Moreover, since `""` is an empty `String`, it doesn't matter which font size you are defining, because you aren't writing anything anyway. Unless it's your intention to change the font size of `"Mango"`, `"Apple"` and `"Orange"`, but that doesn't seem what you're asking. If that's what you're asking, it's very weird that you change the font size of the list symbol, but not the font size of the list items.

Comment: My intention was to change the size of "Mango", "Apple",... and the below answer was what I expected. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure this isn't what you want:

```
Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 6)
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
List fruitList = new List(List.UNORDERED);
fruitList.add(new ListItem("Mango", font));
fruitList.add(new ListItem("Apple", font));
fruitList.add(new ListItem("Orange", font));
cell.addElement(fruitList);
table.addCell(cell);
```